# UK Business rates if multiple businesses/partners operate in the same unit

Tags: united-kingdom, business, rates

I can't find an answer for this anywhere...

If a business property is rated at £10k and we figure out the business rates as such:
 £10,000 (rateable value) x £0.462p (multiplier) = £4,620 (basic business rates)
(ignoring any deductible allowances)

**If two businesses move in to that property, when allowed by the landlord, and have 50% of the property each, how are the business rates calculated?**

Would you divide the business rates for the property by the number of businesses?
(£4,620 / 2 = £2,310)
£2,310 business rated to be paid by each business.

Or would you take the original rateable value and divide that by 2?
(£10,000 / 2 = £5,000 * £0.462p = £2,310)
Now £2,310 is under the £6,000 small business allowance, £0 would be paid.